# Different actions for each button using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Well, my problem is that I am trying to insert, update and delete sending the data through a form using Ajax but I'm struggling with the submit buttons because I need each one to perform one specific action everytime I click them calling the url where are the php instructions, but as you can see in the Ajax the action only performs on submit and not depending on the button I click, I really need to solve this...

**FORM**

```
    <form method="post" id="form_shirt" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       ID:<br>
       <input type="hidden" name="id_shirt" id="id_shirt" class="form-control" >
       Name:<br>
       <input type="text" name="name_shirt" id="name_shirt" class="form-control" required="required">
       Price:<br>
       <input type="text" name="price_shirt" id="price_shirt" class="form-control" required="required">

        <input type="submit" name="btninsert" id="btninsert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success"/>
        <input type="submit" name="btnupdate" id="btnupdate" value="Update" class="btn btn-warning">
        <input type="submit" name="btndelete" id="btndelete" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger">
   </form>
```

**AJAX**

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
 $('#form_shirts').on("submit", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();  
   $.ajax({  
    url:"insert_shirts.php",  
    method:"POST",  
    data:new FormData(this), 
    contentType: false,       
    cache: false,             
    processData:false,
    success:function(data){  
     $('#form_shirt')[0].reset();
     $('#table_shirt').html(data);
    }  
   });  
 });


 $('#form_shirts').on("submit", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();  
   $.ajax({  
    url:"update_shirts.php",  
    method:"POST",  
    data:new FormData(this), 
    contentType: false,       
    cache: false,             
    processData:false,
    success:function(data){  
     $('#form_shirt')[0].reset();
     $('#table_shirt').html(data);
    }  
   });  
 });


     $('#form_shirts').on("submit", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();  
       $.ajax({  
        url:"delete_shirts.php",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:new FormData(this), 
        contentType: false,       
        cache: false,             
        processData:false,
        success:function(data){  
         $('#form_shirt')[0].reset();
         $('#table_shirt').html(data);
        }  
       });  
     });

});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "shirts");

 $output = '';
    $name_shirt = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name_shirt"]);  
    $price_shirt = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["price_shirt"]);  

    $query = "INSERT into shirts ( name, price)
    VALUES ('$name_shirt','$price_shirt') ";
    if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
    {
     $output .= '<label class="text-success">Data Inserted</label>';
     $select_query = "SELECT id_shirt, name, price FROM shirts";
     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $select_query);
     $output .= '
      <table id="shirts" class="table table-bordered">  
                   <thead>
                    <tr>  
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>NAME</th>
                        <th>PRICE</th>
                    </tr>
</thead>
     ';
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $output .= '
       <tr>  
       <tbody>
                         <td>' . $row["id_shirt"] . '</td>
                         <td>' . $row["name"] . '</td>
                         <td>' . $row["price"] . '</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
      ';
     }
     $output .= '</table>';
    }
    echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: you dont need to write .ready for each button click, do 1 document.ready, and move the 3 button click to its own function, and then in the .ready, call the function, your submit is form? change it to button, the click so it should work exactly the same as button click

Comment: So why not give those buttons a class name, set the click event for all buttons with that class and use the ID's to set the name of the PHP file or use the `data-` attribute? That way you have one function working for all three buttons rather than creating 3 functions that do the exactly the same thing other than send data to a different file name...

Comment: You can't have three `<input type="submit">` buttons. Simply have them as regular `<button>` elements, and target them with `on('click')` rather than `on('submit')`.

Comment: Thinking a little out of the box, could you have one submit button and a radio button group with three buttons tied to the three options: `insert`, `update`, and `delete`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have three  buttons for a single form. Simply create three buttons that will have unique class names, in addition to a synonymous class that you can reference on button click. Then reference the **click** handler for that synonymous class (rather than the form submission):

**HTML**:

```
<form method="post" id="form_shirt" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  ID:
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="id_shirt" id="id_shirt" class="form-control"> Name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="name_shirt" id="name_shirt" class="form-control" required="required"> Price:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="price_shirt" id="price_shirt" class="form-control" required="required">

  <button name="btninsert" id="btninsert" value="Insert" class="submit insert_shirts btn btn-success" />
  <button name="btnupdate" id="btnupdate" value="Update" class="submit update_shirts btn btn-warning" />
  <button name="btndelete" id="btndelete" value="Delete" class="submit delete_shirts btn btn-danger" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submit').on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.classList[1] + ".php",
      method: "POST",
      data: new FormData(this),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#form_playera')[0].reset();
        $('#table_playeras').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Note that you can have the three separate functions in one `$(document).ready()`, and the three functions can all be combined into one, sending different `url` parameters to AJAX by using **[this.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)**: `url: this.classList[1] + ".php"`. The `1` denotes the second class of each element (`insert_shirts`, `update_shirts` and `delete_shirts` respectively).

Also note that you won't need `event.preventDefault()`, as you're no longer targeting the form submission.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I think this might be the solution but whenever I click on the button insert_shirts It doesn't do anything :/

Comment: Oh, I see. You already had IDs defined after the name. Yes, this will probably not work due to a conflict. Give me two minutes and I'll revert my answer back to the class option :)

Comment: I've updated my answer, and the buttons should work now :)

Comment: The same thing still happening, It should insert the data that is in the form however only cleans my form and doesn't insert

Comment: I did the corrections and now the button calls the php file but now tells me **Notice: Undefined index: name_shirt** and the same with the price_shirt, do I have to do something different in the php to make it work?

Comment: I've updated my question with the php file for insert