# Php is not properly recieving data that is in my form

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm using Ajax to send the values of my form to my php file and insert it in my data base, depending on the action of the button it will execute the url,
in this case is insert_shirt.php, but It doesn't seem to be working because It doesn't send the data that is the form like as if the form were completely empty

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" id="form_shirt">
  ID:
  <br>
  <input type="hidden" name="id_shirt" id="id_shirt" class="form-control"> Name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="name_shirt" id="name_shirt" class="form-control" required="required"> Price:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="price_shirt" id="price_shirt" class="form-control" required="required">

  <button id="insert_shirt" class="submit" name="btninsert">INSERT</button>

</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submit').on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.id + ".php",
      method: "POST",
      data: $('#form_shirt').serialize(),
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#form_shirt')[0].reset();
        $('#table_shirt').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "shirts");

 $output = '';
    $name_shirt = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name_shirt"]);  
    $price_shirt = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["price_shirt"]);  

    $query = "INSERT into shirts ( name, price)
    VALUES ('$name_shirt','$price_shirt') ";
    if(mysqli_query($connect, $query))
    {
     $output .= '<label class="text-success">Data Inserted</label>';
     $select_query = "SELECT id_shirt, name, price FROM shirts";
     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $select_query);
     $output .= '
      <table id="shirts" class="table table-bordered">  
                   <thead>
                    <tr>  
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>NAME</th>
                        <th>PRICE</th>
                    </tr>
</thead>
     ';
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
      $output .= '
       <tr>  
       <tbody>
                         <td>' . $row["id_shirt"] . '</td>
                         <td>' . $row["name"] . '</td>
                         <td>' . $row["price"] . '</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
      ';
     }
     $output .= '</table>';
    }
    echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: I remember seeing you post a question related to this source code but I have also noticed in your previous question the php file name is different. Here you are using `insert_shirt.php` but in your previous question you use `insert_shirts.php` so I'm just wondering could it be possible that it's a simple typo by missing the **s** from the file name insert_shirt**s**.php https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203798/different-actions-for-each-button-using-ajax

Comment: What do you see in Chrome developer when you make a this request.  It is a POST request but the data you are sending is in the format id_shirt=&name_shirt=12.99&price_shirt=shirt which is what you would normally send via GET request. Just wondering.

Comment: @JarekKulikowski So.. if I change all the POST request to GET it should work?

Comment: You could try it.  If the server is receiving the request and is expecting GET then it should. Ah wait.  In your PHP code you are expecting _POST.  Maybe if you change that to _GET.

Comment: @NewToJS It's because when I posted my question I tried to simplify the code and maybe I erased by accident an **s**

Comment: I don't think it's a matter of changing $_POST to $_GET because you are using POST in the $.ajax() call. I would take a look at Kira San's answer. contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" is actually the default so you can simply omit the contentType prop in your $.ajax() call instead of changing it from false to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",

Comment: In terms of coming up with steps for troubleshooting this sort of thing, step one would be to open Chrome dev tools, go to NETWORK panel and click "XHR". This is where you would see Ajax requests. You can click on Ajax requests in that tab to see what is being sent. Also, your $.ajax() call should have an error handler. Finally, on the PHP side, You can var_dump() $_POST to see what it contains. Also, might want to wrap the form handling PHP code in: if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {}. (This way it doesn't run unless a POST request was sent)

Comment: @NeilGirardi I did what you told me, I put the var_dump()$_POST to see what was the content and this is what it returned `array(1) { ["------WebKitFormBoundaryuQqjfylxcTpuTZz1-- "]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: I wouldn't go changing all my POSTs to GETs, either should technically work, but given you are POSTing data to the db, I would stick with those. Use them literally!

Comment: try  changing data: $('#form_shirt').serialize(),  to data: {posthis: $('#form_shirt').serialize()}   and var_dump($_POST) in your php file.

Comment: Try getting rid of processData: false in your Ajax call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"` which is the default value if you didn't include it in your request. You are setting it to `false` which could be why your `$_POST` doesn't see your form data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but after I add that still happening the same thing, it doesn't insert :/

Comment: Look at Dev tools -> Network tab. Do you see your request reaching the server?

Comment: Yeah, the request is reaching the server, it shows me status 200

Comment: OK, now try to `var_dump($_POST)`. On your dev tools network tab, look at the request response.

Comment: It should show me the values that I send in the dev tools network tab? because the only thing that show me after I try with `var_dump($_POST)` is the same thing as before, name: insert_shirt.php, status:200 type:xhr

Comment: Yes click on that request, the details will open, then go to response tab to read the server response.

Comment: Ok, this is what got `array(1) {
  ["------WebKitFormBoundaryVhwhaPer5jzDZpUV--
"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: name_shirt in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\admon2x\insert_shirt.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: price_shirt in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\admon2x\insert_shirt.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />`

Comment: Ok looks like your $_POST array is empty. Inspect the request again, on the first tab, scroll down to your post request data, see what you're sending to the server.

Comment: Ok, now try to omit `contentType`. There's something wrong with FormData.

Comment: I did it and the same thing happens

Comment: In dev tools console, what does this `$('#form_shirt').serialize()` output?

Comment: It only prints `array(0) {}`

Comment: That's weird, are you sure your actual form is the same as you posted?

Comment: Wait, you were right with `$('#form_shirt').serialize()` I missed a letter haha, now the array is not empty, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

try using the ajax .post method like this
and be sure to include the action="{your php file}" in the form tag

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.submit').on("click", function() {
    var id = $('#id_shirt').val();
    var name = $('#name_shirt').val();
    var price = $('#price_shirt').val();
    $.post("{your php file}",
        {
          id_shirt: id,
          name_shirt: name,
          price_shirt: price,
        },
        function(data,status){
            $('#form_shirt')[0].reset();
            $('#table_shirt').html(data);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

here is a link to the w3 manual for ajax .post and .get
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp